# How to export PivotGridControl data asynchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm using the `DevExpress.Xpf.PivotGrid.PivotGridControl` and the user wants to load a lot of data (+50,000). After that he wants to export that data.

I'm calling this method:

```
this.pivotGridControl.ExportToCsv("C:\\example.csv");
```

It works but since it is a lot of data it hangs my UI for almost 10 seconds.

Since `pivotGridControl` is an instance of a control in the UI I know I can't use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `BackgroundWorker`. Both throw the below message (without inner exception):

`The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.`

Is it possible to export data from a PivotGridControl without block the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new thread

```
        var ExportToCsvThread = new Thread(x => this.pivotGridControl.ExportToCsv("C:\\example.csv"););
        ExportToCsvThread.Name = "ExportToCsv Thread";
        ExportToCsvThread.Start();
```

Comment: Same problem as `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `BackgroundWorker`. Can't acess `pivotGridControl` because it is owned by the dispatcher thread.

Comment: I susuppose you will advise to do a copy of the data to another control witout using it in UI. Yeah, already considered this but I playing hight on memory. I think it will duplicate, right? ;)